# Why don't CSS transitions fire when triggered via trigger.click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't understand why CSS transitions do not run when they are called via a trigger event but they do run when called via a mouse click.

I'm referring to this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sopgxLLc/). (My event hookups are at the bottom of the JS panel)

```
<button id="notworks">notworks</button>
<button class="dl-trigger">works</button>
```

The first button is simply triggering the click event of the second. This does not run the associated CSS transitions but it does fire the event and the `console.log` output is exactly the same... so I know a handler for the click event is firing and being passed through regardless of trigger method.

```
 $("#notworks").click(function () {
       $('.dl-trigger').trigger('click');
 });
```

However the `CSS` transitions only run with a direct click on the second button with class `dl-trigger`. I've tested `this` in both cases and it's the same reference regardless of whether there is a direct click or a triggered click.

So this code block is run regardless of which button is clicked:

```
 _initEvents: function () {

            var self = this;
            this.$trigger.on('click.dlmenu', function () {

                if (self.open) {
                    self._closeMenu();
                }
                else {
                    self._openMenu();
                }
                return false;

            });
```

I can trace the calls into open and close as well and confirm that it all run swithout error as well. But the menu simply doesn't show for the first button click.

Is there some kind of not-my-code lookup that occurs when using 'CSS' transitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up with your chat room question, the code below returns `false`.

```
this.$trigger.on('click.dlmenu', function () {
   if (self.open) {
      self._closeMenu();
   }
   else {
      self._openMenu();
   }
   return false;
});
```

Returning false from a jquery event handler will suppress the event and is equivalent to calling:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

So returning `false` suppresses the event and this is important because in the `openMenu` function the code adds a handler to close the menu when you click anywhere outside it's bounds:

```
   $body.off('click').on('click.dlmenu', function () {
          self._closeMenu();
   });
```

So if the code didn't return false and suppress the event, it would propagate to the body and immediately close the menu again. So that's what happens when clicking the regular `menuOpen` button.

However since you tried to trigger/simulate a click of that button with another button via:

```
   $("#notworks").click(function (e) {
       $('.dl-trigger').trigger('click');
   });
```

Then that button `notworks` is now propagating a click, which is picked up by the body handler and immediately closing your menu that was opened by the trigger call.

So you just need to cancel the propagation:

```
   $("#notworks").click(function (e) {
       $('.dl-trigger').trigger('click');
       return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **notworks** now turns to **works** ;)

```
$("#notworks").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $('.dl-trigger').trigger('click');
                });
```

Fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sopgxLLc/6/)

Comment: Ok great thanks. Can you explain what difference that makes?

Comment: Because the outer div (#dl-menu) also has the event. So I use `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent the event from any outer parent of #notworks button.